# Why all constants not loading on pry console in rails project root dir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I have a rails project named food_delight and I have been using pry in place of irb, now my problem is "When I do 'pry' to enter in pry console inside rails project root dir non of the ActiveRecord classes are found but when I do 'rails console' in same rot directry then all the classes are autoloaded. Why this type of behavior, please explain in detail since I'm new to rails only 2-3 months and I'm learning alot.

Comment: Which gem you are using of PRY? did you check the https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails PRY RAILS?

Comment: For the same reason simply typing `irb` doesn't load all said constants. `irb` and `pry` are plain Ruby consoles. Add [pry rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) and type `rails c`, it will now use `pry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the comments, what's being said is to install the `pry-rails` gem in your Gemfile.

`pry` alone works the same as `irb` (a Ruby console, outside of the project's context), while using `pry-rails` means `rails c` will load using `pry` with all its functionality. And therefore access to the required constants.

This will also allow you to use the `binding.pry` breakpoints within the code, as desired.

Alternatively, if you load `rails c` with the `pry` gem installed, you should be able to run the command `pry` within that (you *might* need to `require 'pry'` ahead of this), and it jump to using `pry` within the project's context. This will be handy if you're not able to add the `pry-rails` gem to the project's dependencies.

(Whew - that's a lot of `'pry's`.)

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.